# SVM with Tensorflow

Tags: classification, tensorflow, svm

I have an array of Numpy with the following data, for example:

```
['13 .398249765480822 ''19 .324784598731966' '80 .98629514090669 '
  '-3.703122956721927e-06' '80 .98629884402965 ''24 .008452881790028'
  '679.6408224307851' '2498.8247399799975', 'fear']
```

And another array of Numpy with the same length and different numbers and another label that is 'neutral'.

The fact is that I'm using the code (Setosa) of Github and other articles to make a binary classifier (fear or neutral) but I get the following error because I do not know how to do so that I take into account all the numbers in the array and not as the code of Setosa, which only takes into account two when performing the mesh.

```
## SVM con Tensorflow
sess = tf.Session()
x_vals = np.array([[x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]] for x in matrix])
y_vals = np.array([1 if y[8] == 'fear' else -1 for y in matrix])

# Split the train data and testing data
train_indices = np.random.choice(len(x_vals), int(round(len(x_vals)*0.8)), replace=False)
test_indices = np.array(list(set(range(len(x_vals))) - set(train_indices)))
x_vals_train = x_vals[train_indices]
x_vals_test = x_vals[test_indices]
y_vals_train = y_vals[train_indices]
y_vals_test = y_vals[test_indices]

class1_x = [x[0] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == 1]
class1_y = [x[1] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == 1]
class2_x = [x[0] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == -1]
class2_y = [x[1] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == -1]

# Declare batch size
batch_size = 150

# Initialize placeholders
x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 8], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
prediction_grid = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 8], dtype=tf.float32)

# Create variables for svm
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1, batch_size]))

# Gaussian (RBF) kernel
gamma = tf.constant(-10.0)
sq_dists = tf.multiply(2., tf.matmul(x_data, tf.transpose(x_data)))
my_kernel = tf.exp(tf.multiply(gamma, tf.abs(sq_dists)))

# Compute SVM Model
first_term = tf.reduce_sum(b)
b_vec_cross = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(b), b)
y_target_cross = tf.matmul(y_target, tf.transpose(y_target))
second_term = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(my_kernel, tf.multiply(b_vec_cross, y_target_cross)))
loss = tf.negative(tf.subtract(first_term, second_term))

# Gaussian (RBF) prediction kernel
rA = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x_data), 1), [-1, 1])
rB = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(prediction_grid), 1), [-1, 1])
pred_sq_dist = tf.add(tf.subtract(rA, tf.multiply(2., tf.matmul(x_data, tf.transpose(prediction_grid)))), tf.transpose(rB))
pred_kernel = tf.exp(tf.multiply(gamma, tf.abs(pred_sq_dist)))

prediction_output = tf.matmul(tf.multiply(tf.transpose(y_target), b), pred_kernel)
prediction = tf.sign(prediction_output - tf.reduce_mean(prediction_output))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.squeeze(prediction), tf.squeeze(y_target)), tf.float32))

# Declare optimizer
my_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train_step = my_opt.minimize(loss)

# Initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

# Training loop
loss_vec = []
batch_accuracy = []
for i in range(300):
    rand_index = np.random.choice(len(x_vals), size=batch_size)
    rand_x = x_vals[rand_index]
    rand_y = np.transpose([y_vals[rand_index]])
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_data: rand_x, y_target: rand_y})

    temp_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x_data: rand_x, y_target: rand_y})
    loss_vec.append(temp_loss)

    acc_temp = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x_data: rand_x,
                                             y_target: rand_y,
                                             prediction_grid: rand_x})
    batch_accuracy.append(acc_temp)

    if (i + 1) % 75 == 0:
        print('Step #' + str(i + 1))
        print('Loss = ' + str(temp_loss))

# Create a mesh to plot points in
x_vals = x_vals.astype(np.float)
x_min, x_max = x_vals[:, 0].min() - 1, x_vals[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = x_vals[:, 1].min() - 1, x_vals[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.02),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.02))
grid_points = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
[grid_predictions] = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x_data: x_vals,
                                                     y_target: np.transpose([y_vals]),
                                                     prediction_grid: grid_points})
grid_predictions = grid_predictions.reshape(xx.shape)

# Plot points and grid
plt.contourf(xx, yy, grid_predictions, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(class1_x, class1_y, 'ro', label='I. setosa')
plt.plot(class2_x, class2_y, 'kx', label='Non setosa')
plt.title('Gaussian SVM Results on Iris Data')
plt.xlabel('Petal Length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal Width')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.ylim([-0.5, 3.0])
plt.xlim([3.5, 8.5])
plt.show()

# Plot batch accuracy
plt.plot(batch_accuracy, 'k-', label='Accuracy')
plt.title('Batch Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()

# Plot loss over time
plt.plot(loss_vec, 'k-')
plt.title('Loss per Generation')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.show()
```

The error obtained is:

```
File "test.py", line 154, in <module>
    prediction_grid: grid_points})
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (30119320, 2) for Tensor u'Placeholder_2:0', which has shape '(?, 8)'
```

I know they do not have the same shape but I do not know how to change it or what to do because I need to make a classifier with the 8 features and with the two classes, 'neutral' and 'fear'.

Original code is [here](https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/master/04_Support_Vector_Machines/05_Implementing_Nonlinear_SVMs/05_nonlinear_svm.ipynb).

Comment: Please provide a link to the code for later references.

Answer (score 1):

This code is written only for 2D inputs, it cannot be used for 8D inputs.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497004/5341713) on stackoverflow for tensorflow's SVM `tf.contrib.learn.SVM`.

Also, here is an easy to use [SVM example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) in python (without tensorflow).

**About the code**

The 2D assumption is deeply integrated into the code for `prediction_grid` variable and the plots.

An important section is when a grid needs to be created:

```
x_min, x_max = x_vals[:, 0].min() - 1, x_vals[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = x_vals[:, 1].min() - 1, x_vals[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.02),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.02))
grid_points = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
```

which creates a $150^2 \times 2$ `grid_points`. This grid is later used for 2D plots. Since `grid_points` size is $150^d \times d$, it raises `MemoryError` for 8D (even for 4D).

Here is an altered version of the code that I used to experiment with higher dimensions. It avoids `Memory Error` by changing the grid step from 0.02 to 1, thus decreasing $150^d$ to $3^d$ (increase the `grid_step` for wider ranges of inputs).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dimension = 8
N = 300
grid_step = 1  # default value was 0.02

x_dummy = np.random.random((N, dimension))
y_dummy = np.random.choice(['fear', 'abc'], (N, 1))
matrix = np.hstack((x_dummy, y_dummy))

## SVM con Tensorflow
sess = tf.Session()
x_vals = np.array([x[0:dimension] for x in matrix])
y_vals = np.array([1 if y[dimension] == 'fear' else -1 for y in matrix])

# Split the train data and testing data
train_indices = np.random.choice(len(x_vals), int(round(len(x_vals)*0.8)), replace=False)
test_indices = np.array(list(set(range(len(x_vals))) - set(train_indices)))
x_vals_train = x_vals[train_indices]
x_vals_test = x_vals[test_indices]
y_vals_train = y_vals[train_indices]
y_vals_test = y_vals[test_indices]

class1_x = [x[0] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == 1]
class1_y = [x[1] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == 1]
class2_x = [x[0] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == -1]
class2_y = [x[1] for i, x in enumerate(x_vals_train) if y_vals_train[i] == -1]

# Declare batch size
batch_size = N

# Initialize placeholders
x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, dimension], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
prediction_grid = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, dimension], dtype=tf.float32)

# Create variables for svm
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1, batch_size]))

# Gaussian (RBF) kernel
gamma = tf.constant(-10.0)
sq_dists = tf.multiply(2., tf.matmul(x_data, tf.transpose(x_data)))
my_kernel = tf.exp(tf.multiply(gamma, tf.abs(sq_dists)))

# Compute SVM Model
first_term = tf.reduce_sum(b)
b_vec_cross = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(b), b)
y_target_cross = tf.matmul(y_target, tf.transpose(y_target))
second_term = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(my_kernel, tf.multiply(b_vec_cross, y_target_cross)))
loss = tf.negative(tf.subtract(first_term, second_term))

# Gaussian (RBF) prediction kernel
rA = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x_data), 1), [-1, 1])
rB = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(prediction_grid), 1), [-1, 1])
pred_sq_dist = tf.add(tf.subtract(rA, tf.multiply(2., tf.matmul(x_data, tf.transpose(prediction_grid)))), tf.transpose(rB))
pred_kernel = tf.exp(tf.multiply(gamma, tf.abs(pred_sq_dist)))

prediction_output = tf.matmul(tf.multiply(tf.transpose(y_target), b), pred_kernel)
prediction = tf.sign(prediction_output - tf.reduce_mean(prediction_output))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.squeeze(prediction), tf.squeeze(y_target)), tf.float32))

# Declare optimizer
my_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train_step = my_opt.minimize(loss)

# Initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

# Training loop
loss_vec = []
batch_accuracy = []
for i in range(300):
    rand_index = np.random.choice(len(x_vals), size=batch_size)
    rand_x = x_vals[rand_index]
    rand_y = np.transpose([y_vals[rand_index]])
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_data: rand_x, y_target: rand_y})

    temp_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x_data: rand_x, y_target: rand_y})
    loss_vec.append(temp_loss)

    acc_temp = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x_data: rand_x,
                                             y_target: rand_y,
                                             prediction_grid: rand_x})
    batch_accuracy.append(acc_temp)

    if (i + 1) % 75 == 0:
        print('Step #' + str(i + 1))
        print('Loss = ' + str(temp_loss))

# Create a mesh to plot points in
x_vals = x_vals.astype(np.float)
# this code is used as a generalization to work with all dimensions
x_ranges = np.vstack((x_vals.min(axis=0) - 1, x_vals.max(axis=0) + 1)).T
aranges = [np.arange(x_range[0], x_range[1], grid_step) for x_range in x_ranges]
print('grid size:', np.power(len(aranges[0]), dimension))
meshes = np.meshgrid(*aranges)
grid_points = np.vstack(tuple([mesh.ravel() for mesh in meshes])).T
print('grid size:', grid_points.shape)
[grid_predictions] = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x_data: x_vals,
                                                     y_target: np.transpose([y_vals]),
                                                     prediction_grid: grid_points})

# Plot points and grid
# this is the old mesh generation code that is kept since it is used in the plots
x_min, x_max = x_vals[:, 0].min() - 1, x_vals[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = x_vals[:, 1].min() - 1, x_vals[:, 1].max() + 1
xx_arange = np.arange(x_min, x_max, grid_step)
yy_arange = np.arange(y_min, y_max, grid_step)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx_arange,yy_arange)
size = np.power(len(xx), 2)
grid_predictions = grid_predictions[0:size].reshape(xx.shape)

plt.contourf(xx, yy, grid_predictions, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(class1_x, class1_y, 'ro', label='I. setosa')
plt.plot(class2_x, class2_y, 'kx', label='Non setosa')
plt.title('Gaussian SVM Results on Iris Data')
plt.xlabel('Petal Length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal Width')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.ylim([-0.5, 3.0])
plt.xlim([3.5, 8.5])
plt.show()

# Plot batch accuracy
plt.plot(batch_accuracy, 'k-', label='Accuracy')
plt.title('Batch Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()

# Plot loss over time
plt.plot(loss_vec, 'k-')
plt.title('Loss per Generation')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Step #75
Loss = -251.9497
Step #150
Loss = -476.96854
Step #225
Loss = -701.92444
Step #300
Loss = -927.2843
grid size: 6561
grid size: (6561, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Therefore, if I have understood correctly there is no way to perform SVM with Tensorflow with an 8D dimension.
Is there another way to perform SVM with 8D as you say without being Tensorflow? I have to do it in python for my teacher (he does it in Matlab with 22D)

Comment: @Manu I’m happy to help.

Comment: @Manu you can use SVM for way higher dimensions, just not THIS code. I've added another non-tensorflow resource, see if it helps.

Comment: with you code I obtained this error: ValueError: broadcast dimensions too large. In meshes = np.meshgrid(*aranges)

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: @Manu I've managed to reproduce your error. Your value range is wider, thus you need to increase the `grid_step` more. Updated the code, now grid size will be printed before `Memory Error` crash.

Comment: Okay, tomorrow I will try and inform you. I would like to have your email to contact you if more questions arise if it does not bother you. If not, I delete my previous comment so that people do not see my mail.

Comment: @Manu if comments get too long we go into a chat, I prefer communications to be only through the platform. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi!, this is the new output: ('grid size:', 24759631762948096) and ValueError: broadcast dimensions too large. If I change the value of grid_step to 100 if it seems to show something else because it is ('grid size:', 256)

Comment: @Manu so that's it, grid was too large. I suggest using the other options, this code has been written for a special 2D purpose.